# Need to Install PyOpenGL (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, pip, installation, pyopengl

I am trying to install PyOpenGL using pip on Windows 10.
I have tried to install it using pip install PyOpenGL and it tells me that it has installed it successfully but when I try to use PyOpenGL in python, it tells me that I do not have a module named PyOpenGL. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: It is windows 7

Comment: My OS has now been updated to windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

Go to [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Download a 32 bit or 64 bit package for [PyOpenGL provides bindings to OpenGL, GLUT, and GLE](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl)
(e.g.
*PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl* and
*PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl*)

Open Command Prompt (cmd.exe) as administrator. Change to the download directory and install the packages by `pip install packagename.whl`.

e.g:

```
pip install PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

and

```
pip install PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

If the package is already installed, but doesn't work, then you have to ignore the currently installed package, by the option `--ignore-installed`:

```
pip install --ignore-installed PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

```
pip install --ignore-installed PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this did not work. It said Requirement already satisfied: PyOpenGL==3.1.5 from file:///C:/Users/Sailaja/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl in c:\users\sailaja\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (3.1.5) but when I went to import PyOpenGl,it would not work. THank al the same.

Comment: @lavnalla You have to uninstall the wrongly installed package first: `pip uninstall pyopengl`. Then install the downloaded *whl* packages. Or `pip install --ignore-installed ....`

Comment: Thank you, I had to uninstall pyopengl with `conda uninstall pyopengl` (**not** `conda uninstall -c anaconda pyopengl` (that uninstalled all packages, not just pyopengl)). Also had to select the right python version files, since I used a python 3.6 envirionment, I needed the `..cp36..` files. Likewise if you use python 3.x you need the `..cp3x..` files. Also I needed the AMD 64 files even though I think my device is not an amd (it is 64 bit though). I did not need the `--ignore-installed..` commands because I installed a not working `pyopengl` version from conda iso from a wheel.